# My TensorFlow Graph is abnormally large using Edward

Tags: tensorflow, bayesian

I have code here that I've modified from this [website](https://alpha-i.co/blog/MNIST-for-ML-beginners-The-Bayesian-Way.html).  Basically what I have written is this:

```
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
#from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
from edward.models import Categorical, Normal
import edward as ed
#ed.set_seed(39)

import pandas as pd
import csv



# Use the TensorFlow method to download and/or load the data.
with open ("data_final.csv", "r") as csvfile:
    reader1 = csv.reader(csvfile)
    data1 = np.array(list(reader1)).astype(np.float)



#mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)


N = data1.shape[0] -1   # number of images in a minibatch.
D = 4   # number of features.
K = 4    # number of classes.

# Create a placeholder to hold the data (in minibatches) in a TensorFlow graph.
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [N, D])
# Normal(0,1) priors for the variables. Note that the syntax assumes TensorFlow 1.1.
w = Normal(loc=tf.zeros([D, K]), scale=tf.ones([D, K]))
b = Normal(loc=tf.zeros(K), scale=tf.ones(K))
# Categorical likelihood for classication.
y =tf.matmul(x,w)+b

# Contruct the q(w) and q(b). in this case we assume Normal distributions.
qw = Normal(loc=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([D, K])),
              scale=tf.nn.softplus(tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([D, K])))) 
qb = Normal(loc=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([K])),
              scale=tf.nn.softplus(tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([K]))))

# We use a placeholder for the labels in anticipation of the traning data.
y_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [N, K])
# Define the VI inference technique, ie. minimise the KL divergence between q and p.
inference = ed.KLqp({w: qw, b: qb}, data={y:y_ph})

# Initialse the infernce variables
inference.initialize(n_iter=5000, n_print=100, scale={y: 1})

# We will use an interactive session.
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
# Initialise all the vairables in the session.
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
```

I use the data linked [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Kz5NTvWjJuLV9rcW94NVVFTXc), to run the code.  I get an error after less than a second of running the code (so I have a hard time believing this actually happened) that said:

> ValueError: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.

I think there were other topics with the same error as mine, but those people had instantiated like 1 million parameters of something.  I have on the order to 20 parameters, so unsure why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there were still variables (and likely a graphs) that were not garbage collected from a previous Edward runs.  Garbage collecting/resetting the console fixed the problem.

Comment: Note that this also occurs if you run in an ipython notebook.